# Show mat-error conditionally using a different formController than that used in shown input

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have the following situation:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type = "text"
           title = "patientId"
           matInput
           [formControl] = "patientSearchFc"
           [placeholder] = "bookingFieldMap?.patientId.fieldLabel"
           [matAutocomplete] = "patientAutocomplete" />

    <mat-error *ngIf = "bookingFormModel.patientId.dirty && bookingFormModel.patientId.hasError('required')">
      Patient is required.
    </mat-error>

    <mat-hint *ngIf = "selectedPatient">{{'global.selected' | translate}}: 
      {{selectedPatient.someLabel}}</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-autocomplete #patientAutocomplete = "matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor = "let patient of patients"
                [value] = "patient.someLabel"
                (onSelectionChange) = "onPatientSelection(patient)">

      {{ patient.someLabel}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

As it can be seen from the example, I am using a different controller to show mat-error (patientId), and not using the controller actually connected with the input (patientSearchFc). The reason is, I want to use a different controller to search for the patient, and a different one to use as the actual value selected from the list of results. I update the status of the patientId controller to dirty and touched the moment the user types something.

```
  this.patientSearchFc.valueChanges
  .delay(750)
  .subscribe((patientSearchValue) => {
    this._getPatients(patientSearchValue ? patientSearchValue : undefined);
    this.bookingFormModel.patientId.markAsDrity();
    this.bookingFormModel.patientId.markAsTouched();
  });

  onPatientSelection(patient: Person) {
    this.selectedPatient = patient;
  }

  private _getPatients(patientNameSearch?) {
    this._personService.getPersons$({params: {paramBean: {firstName: 
        patientNameSearch}}})
       .onStatusOk$
       .subscribe((res) => {
         this.patients = res.getList();
       });
     }
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uw5mj8?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Currently no error is shown. Any ideas?

Comment: Without your Typescript logic and the other model, we won't be able to help.

Comment: @trichetriche I provided what I think is neccessary.

Comment: The whole code please. And if you don't understand, let me explain it to you : what is `bookingFormModel` ? To which form is `patientSearchFc` bound to ? Is `bookingFormModel` correctly created ? Does `onPatientSelection` have a role to play in your validation ? Why do you post the code of an autocomplete when you don't rely on it in your issue ? And there are many, many more questions. So post your code, or make an example on stackblitz (please).

Comment: @trichetriche I provided a link to stackblitz that ilustrates my problem more simply

Comment: Thanks, I'm home now (and on my phone), but I will take a look at that and give you an answer first thing in the morning tomorrow !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with your blitz, I can tell you that you can't display an error on a material field unless the form control itself has an error. I've found a workaround to your solution that [**you can find here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2au2n?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

All you have to do is to create a custom error that you will bind to the state of your second formControl, and set it to true. Then, you put this error in your `mat-error` tag, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The form field itself needs to be in a state of error in order to display any `<mat-error>` content. That means that the form controller for the form field's input has to have its `errorState` property evaluate to true. So you'll need to tie the two form controllers together somehow to make this work, or simply use just one form controller. A workaround would be to use a hint instead and apply style to make it look like an error, although this may not satisfy application requirements since it really only fakes the look of an error - the field itself would still be in non-error state.

EDIT: A quick and dirty fix for your stackblitz is to pass the errors from your patient id controller to the patient search controller in your patient search controller value change listener:

```
this.patientSearchFc.valueChanges.delay(750).subscribe((value) => {
  this.patientIdFc.markAsDirty();
  this.patientIdFc.markAsTouched();
  this.patientSearchFc.setErrors(this.patientIdFc.errors);
});
```